# How to call cd command using a path?

Tags: ios, c, bash, unix, terminal

I want to call `cd` command inside my tool but there isn't a path for it because it is a builtin command.

I've managed to call `mkdir` using `/bin/mkdir`.

What is the path to use for `cd`?

This is the code for `mkdir`:

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
const char *argv[] = {"mkdir", "Folder", NULL};
posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/mkdir", NULL, NULL, (char* const*)argv, NULL);
waitpid(pid, &status, WEXITED);
```

Comment: @cdarke  you mean I can replace/bin/mkdir with cd

Comment: From C, use `chdir()`, not `cd`.   Do a `man 2 chdir`.  Even if you did spawn a `cd` in a child process, it would not affect the parent.

Comment: @cdarke can u explain more please using the code above?

Comment: Don't use `posix_spawn`, it would ave no effect on your current process anyway.  There is actually no need to use it for `mkdir` either.  I'll do an example if you give me a few minutes.

Comment: for POSIX systems, see [`chdir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html). `cd` is a builtin for a reason: you can only change the current directory of *your* process, never that of a parent process.

Comment: with "which mkdir" you get the path to the binary

Comment: @Patrick85 so you suggest to spawn *yet another process* and capture its output in order to be able to spawn a process for no reason at all because there is [`mkdir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir)?

Comment: Even the program `mkdir(1)` is a relatively thin wrapper around the system call `mkdir(2)`; you wouldn't use the former from inside your own program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly standard way to change directory of the current process.  I have dropped the spawn of a child process, which is unnecessary:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int status;
    const char *argv[] = {"mkdir", "Folder", NULL};

    status = mkdir(argv[1], S_IRWXU);
    if (status != 0 && errno != EEXIST) {
        perror("mkdir");
        exit(1);
    }

    status = chdir(argv[1]);
    if (status != 0) {
        perror("chdir");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Print current directory name
    char buffer[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    printf("%s\n", getcwd(buffer, PATH_MAX));

    return 0;

}
```

The error handling and the permissions are fairly simplistic, you might want to enhance those.